# format title entry in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying for typeset a list of publications using `biblatex` and would like to change entry titles to sentence case (or uppercase/lowercase/titlecase). I tried to use `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}` but it doesn't seem to work.

MWE:

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pub.bib}
@article{article1,
    author={Author One and Author Two},
    title={Title of Article One},
    date= {2018},
    }
@article{article2,
    author={Author One and Author Two},
    title={Title of article two},
    date= {2017},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt,
    giveninits=true,
    maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\MakeCapital{#1}}   % Change titles to sentence case
\addbibresource{pub.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article, title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A warm welcome to the site!!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `titlecase` for that.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
```

A full MWE:

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{pub.bib}
@article{article1,
    author={Author One and Author Two},
    title={Title of Article One},
    date= {2018},
    }
@article{article2,
    author={Author One and Author Two},
    title={Title of article two},
    date= {2017},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    sorting=ynt,
    giveninits=true,
    maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}   % Change titles to sentence case
\addbibresource{pub.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[type=article, title={Publications}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: Perhaps an explanation of why `titlecase` rather than `title` should be used may be useful here. If we look at the definition of the macro `title` in `biblatex.def` we will find the following:

```
\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}
```

Notice the formatting directive `[title]` applies to `title + subtitle` printing instructions. That's necessary for it is a common requirement of bibliography styles that the title of some common entrytypes be set between quotes, that is a single pair of quotes for both "title" and "subtitle". The formatting directive `[titlecase]` is applied individually to `title` and `subtitle`. A consequence of this is that if you try to apply `\MakeSentenceCase` to the `title` formatting directive, you will be feeding it a sequence of `\printfield`s and punctuation instructions, with their own individual formatting directives `[titlecase]`. Something which does not behave well, as you noticed. But, even if this was a sanitized string, you would get an undesired lowercase first letter of the subtitle (you would be feeding them both together to `\MakeSentenceCase`). So, in short, the `titlecase` is there as it is exactly to enable one to deal with `title` and `subtitle` separately, and that would be the appropriate scope to apply any sentence casing directives.

Comment: Is it possible to change the case to something other than sentence case? Also, when would `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{}` be used?

Comment: What do you mean by "other than sentence case"? As to when the field formatting directives are used for `title`, as far as the standard styles go, it controls emphasis, quotes etc. It is globally defined as `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` and then redefined for a set of entrytypes as `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}`. That's where the quotes come from in the above example.